# Member initialization Vs Constructor Initialization

Tags: java, oop

Is there a difference between two declarations. Any pros and cons? Which is preferred.

```
class Car
{
   CarLoan loan= new CarLoan();
}
```

VS

```
class Car
{
   CarLoan loan;

   Car()
   {
       loan = new CarLoan();
   }
}
```

I think member initialization is called before constructor call. Is there any other differences?

Comment: Java or C#? They behave differently, in terms of ordering with respect to the base/superclass constructor call.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon. Plz explain in Java, have updated the question.

Comment: In Java I believe the two are equivalent.

Comment: In general, use what you find the clearer, and which avoids repeating yourself. So in this case, I would prefer the first one, which avoids repeating it in every constructor.

Comment: In car constructor, construct the car object and same for CarLoan.

Comment: @JonSkeet Me too think same, can u explain how it differs in C#.

Comment: @MusicMan: In C# instance initializers are executed before the base class constructor, which can affect behaviour if the base class constructor calls virtual methods overridden in the derived class

Answer (score 1):

If you have two or more constructors and intialization value differs in each of them, then you should use constructor initialization as there is no way to do the same with member initialization...

however if you have just one constructor...you can use member initialization for better code clarity...

Comment: Initialization block can be used to handle conditional execution of member initialization. This code works fine.
    public class Car {
       CarLoan loan ;
    {
     if(3<2)
         loan = new CarLoan((int) 10);
     else 
         loan = new CarLoan();
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
         Car car = new Car();
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both of your examples at the end.

But if you have more than one member, the direct initialized members are constructed before the code in the invoked constructor gets called.

You just have to think of it like inlining all the direct initialized mebers in all of your constructors.

You can see it very well in the Eclipse debugger during object creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **pre-initialization** (member initialization) then the JVM will gets a speed boost like the **final** keyword. The class members are initialized with **default values**. That is a benefit.
You are owner about your code. I agree in some cases you maybe change the default values then change it and use the constructor. 
I hope it helps.